# Como transferir de uma ComboBox para outra (C#)

Tags: c#, combobox

A ideia é, existem uma ComboBox Principal, cada um com um cliente de 4 cidades diferentes, eu queria selecionar um cliente na ComboBox, apertar o botão e remover dessa ComboBox e inserir na cidade correspondente dela.

Resumindo: Quero tirar um item, remove-lo e colocar na ComboBox pré selecionada.

Eu tentei usando IF, ja que cada ComboBox começa com 0, mas ao adicionar na ComboBox, ela retorna um valor que contem algo la dentro, mas não mostra nenhum texto.
(Exemplo do que tentei)

```
if (cboClientes.SelectedIndex == 0 || cboClientes.SelectedIndex == 2 || cboClientes.SelectedIndex == 3 || 
{
    cboVarginha.Items.Add(cboClientes.SelectedIndex);
    cboClientes.Items.RemoveAt(cboClientes.SelectedIndex);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pelo que eu entendi, vc quer selecionar um item na `ComboBox`, apertar um botão e move-lo para outro `ComboBox`.

Montei um esquema aqui... espero que sirva.

Imagem:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código Utilizado:

```
        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
                comboBox1.Items.Add($"Item {i}");
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!comboBox1.SelectedIndex.Equals(-1))
            {
                comboBox2.Items.Add(comboBox1.SelectedItem);
                comboBox2.Sorted = true;

                Resultado.Text = $"O Elemento {(string)comboBox1.SelectedItem} foi transferido para o Destino";
                Resultado.Left = (Resultado.Parent.Width / 2) - (Resultado.Width / 2);

                comboBox1.Items.RemoveAt(comboBox1.SelectedIndex);                
                Resultado.Visible = true;
            }
        }
```

Existe também a possibilidade de usar o evento `SelectedIndexChanged` da `ComboBox` e mandar direto para Segunda `ComboBox` no ato da seleção do Item na Primeira.